# Coalesce(), ISNULL() clarification

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently studying for my MCSA Data Platform, I got the following question wrong and I was looking for an explanation as to why my answer was wrong as the in test explanation did not make much sense.

The Hovercraft Wages table records salaries paid to workers at Contoso. Workers get either a daily rate or a yearly salary. The table conatains the following columns:

EmpID, Daily_Rate, Yearly_Salary

Workers only get one type of income rate and the other column in their record has a value of NULL. You want to run a query calculating each employees total salary based on the assumption that people work 5 days a week 52 weeks per year.

Below are two options the right answer and the answer i chose

```
SELECT EmpID, CAST(COALESCE(Daily_Rate*5*52, Yearly_Salary) AS money) AS 'Total Salary'
FROM Hovercraft.Wages;

SELECT EMPID, CAST(ISNULL(Daily_Rate*5*52, Yearly_Salary)AS money)AS 'Total Salary'
FROM Hovercraft.Wages;
```

I selected the second choice as there were only two possible pay fields but was marked as incorrect for the coalesce, Can anybody clarify why an ISNULL is not a valid choice in this example as I do not want to make this mistake in the future

Many Thanks

Comment: In the first query you have Yearly_Rate, in the second Yearly_Salary, is that a typo?

Comment: Yes apologies i'll amend

Comment: Are you sure you copied the question correctly, and that there isn't some other difference?  I'd be surprised if the correct answer depended on such a subtle difference.  You say the "... explanation did not make much sense" - what was this explanation?

Comment: There were two other choices too. Well the explanation said ISNULL enables youtyo replace null values with another value. Which is what I thought the purpose of the question was. I have uploaded an image of the answer page I got to containing the full question [link]http://tinypic.com/r/t5p3e1/8[/link]

Comment: I would put this in the context of Microsoft's own description of how the two work (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx).  Although I am a big fan of using ANSI standard features, you should use `ISNULL()` when the first argument is a subquery or complex function call due for performance reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest difference is that `ISNULL` is proprietary, while `COALESCE` is part of SQL standard. Certification course may be teaching to maximum portability of knowledge, so when you have several choices, the course prefers a standard way of solving the problem.

The other difference that may be important in this situation is the data type determination. `ISNULL` uses the type of the first argument, while `COALESCE` follows the same rules as `CASE`, and picks the type with higher precedence. This may be important when `Daily_Rate` is stored in a column with narrower range.

For completeness, here is a list of other differences between the two ([taken from Microsoft SQL Server Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx)):

- The NULLability of result expression is different,
- Validations for `ISNULL` and `COALESCE` is different, because `NULL` value for `ISNULL` is converted to `int`, but triggers an error with `COALESCE`
- `ISNULL` takes only two parameters whereas `COALESCE` takes variable number of parameters
- You may get different query plans for the two functions.

**EDIT :** From the way the answer is worded I think that the authors want you to use `ISNULL` in situations when the second argument is guaranteed to be non-NULL, e.g. a non-nullable field, or a constant. While generally this idea is sound, their choice of question to test it is not ideal: the issue is that the problem guarantees that the value of the second `ISNULL` parameter is non-NULL in situations when it matters, making the two choices logically equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I was looking at it in the wrong manner rahter than  ISNULL is wrong but Coalesce is the standard solution

Comment: In response to your edit. That was the main cause of my puzzlement when I was checking over my results as I expected to get the mark for that question :)

Answer (score 0):

Besides all the very well known differences, not many people know that `COALESCE` is just a shorthand for `CASE`, and inherits all of it's +s and -s -- a list of parameters, proper casting of the result and so on.

But it also can be detrimonial to performance for an unsuspecting developer.

To demonstrate my point, pls run these three queries (on AdventureWorks2012 database) and check the execution plans for them:

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT CustomerID FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader WHERE SalesOrderId = 57418), 0)

SELECT ISNULL((SELECT CustomerID FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader WHERE SalesOrderId = 57418), 0)

SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT CustomerID FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader WHERE SalesOrderId = 57418) IS NULL 
    THEN 0
    ELSE (SELECT CustomerID FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader WHERE SalesOrderId = 57418)
END
```

You see that the first and the third one have the identicall execution plans (because the COALESCE is just a short form of CASE). Also you see that in first and third queries the SalesOrderHeader table is accessed twice, as oposed to just once with ISNULL.

If you also enable `SET STATISTICS IO ON` for the session, you'll notice that the number of logical reads is double for these two queries.

In this case, `COALESCE` executed the inner SELECT statement twice, as opposed to `ISNULL`, which executed it only once. This could make a huge difference.

Comment: Thanks for the samples. I opted for isnull when amswerimg due to it being a better choice when there are only two values necesssary and was puzzled when isnull was marked as incorrect. In a practicality sense for actually using I would still opt for the isnull however in a test enviroment it appears they were looking for sql standard rather than an environment specific solution